# Adding cost from line shapefile using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, distance, network-analyst

I have a network dataset (a road network), and require a matrix of Cost Distances between many points, which works well.

I have now added a line shapefile (representing rail lines). I wish to use it to add cost when a rail line is crossed. But of course as a line shapefile I am only offered the chance of restriction or scaled cost - but I wish to add a certain value when the rail line is crossed.

I am using Arcmap 10.1 (advanced license).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intersect your rail line and road line data using point as the output geometry type, then add the points to the network as cost barriers. See the second example on the [help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004700000056000000).

Comment: Hi Chris
Ah, I see, many thanks for your help
John